Unity3d UIDocument display grid in USS
I want to achieve the grid like this in Unity UIDocument.
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px);
grid-gap: 1rem;
justify-content: space-between;

If you resize the window you will see the columns are aligned perfectly. So far the space-between, space-even or ::after all doesnt work with undefined size and number of items.
Please let me know if there is something in USS!
Adding the Uxml and USS as requested.

Please edit your question to include the relevant HTML in the question itself. See [mcve] for more information.

@TylerH this isn't HTML but Unity's new UI system "UI Toolkit"

OP please include the relevant code directly in your question rather than through a third party source which in addition isn't suitable for UXML

Please add them to your question, not to a 3rd party site. See the link in my first comment for how to do that.

@derHugo UI Toolkit uses HTML/XML and CSS. This is clearly CSS Grid styles implemented inside Unity. You're welcome to create a [unity-uss] tag if you want additional tag information but the [css] tag is correct here.

@TylerH yes the CSS part is ... But this is not HTML but a custom UXML language.. my comment was an answer to your include the relevant HTML in the question itself .. just a clarification
